# Utilizing spatial index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, intersection, spatial-join, sql-server

I have a table `Points` with `shape` column for points of `geography` type, and a spatial index on the column to improve performance..

```
CREATE TABLE  Points(id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, shape geography);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndx_Points_shape ON Points(shape);
```

I am trying to retrieve all intersecting pairs of points from the Points table with polygon shapes from `shape` column of type `geometry` in another table named `Grids`. Grids table also has a spatial index to optimize spatial queries.

spatial index on Grids table

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [S7434_idx] ON Grids ( [SHAPE] )USING GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID WITH (BOUNDING_BOX =(-120.005720158, 25.837266505, -92.408500871, 49.00098643), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 8, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

intersection query

```
INSERT INTO Intersections(point_id ,grid_id )
SELECT P.id , G.id
FROM Points P
INNER JOIN Grids G
ON G.SHAPE.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromWKB(P.shape.STAsBinary(),4326)) = 1
```

- Attempted using Points table with shape column of type geometry and compare directly so that the types are compatible. However, the execution plan indicates a Clustered Index seek on the Grids table, but it doesn't seem to use the spatial index on the Points table, which might affect query performance.

```
SELECT P.id , G.id
FROM Points P
INNER JOIN Grids G
ON G.SHAPE.STIntersects(P.shape) = 1
```

- Attempted an index hint on Points table column, Execution plan now only does Clustered Index seek on Points table replacing Grids table index.
- Attempted an index hint on both indices, it throws an error that Query processor can't produce a plan.

```
OPTION (TABLE HINT (G, INDEX(S7434_idx)), TABLE HINT (P, INDEX(SIndx_Points_shape)))
```

Can query processor use spatial index of two columns compared in the same condition or it chooses the the index that best optimizes the query from the two? Any ideas as to how to speed up queries like this?

Comment: If you're driving the query with the polygons (which you should, since they're in a one-to-many with the points -- fewer index scans), then it's unlikely that the polygon index would come into play.